# Getting an error while setting up Docker on windows machine

Tags: .net, azure, docker

I am using Windows 10 Enterprise edition x64

Steps i have followed till now:

1) Enabled Virtualisation from BIOS

2) Enabled HyperV

3) Installed Docker CE for windows

Getting following error when i am trying to pull the images using powershell,

[Here is an image showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTqmE.jpg)

Comment: Please, do not use screenshots to post your error. It is annoying. Put it in your question

Comment: It seems like just a connection issue, which has nothing to do with docker requirements. Did you already try it again or with another connection?

Comment: @PeterBons i tried executing that command 3-4 times.

Comment: Please, redirect your command to the log ('command' > log.txt) and post excerpts from the log instead of the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You could restart Docker to fix that issue.
Right click on Docker and go to Settings
On the left pane, select Reset and click on 'Restart Docker'.
After Docker has restarted, try pulling down the image. It should work this time.
Let me know how it went!